# How to make thymeleaf spring security namespace available?

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I've got a Spring Boot app. From what I understand a boot app will only need the dependency in the pom and all is great. Unfortunately, that's not the case and even when I overcomplicate my configuration it still doesn't work - I can't use the `sec` namespace in my pages.

In my page the first issue is the namespace URI:

[image]

I've tried every option available in the Intellij fix menu and can't get it.

I suppose the result of that issue is the fact that I can't use the `sec` namespace anywhere. The pictured example may indeed be an invalid use but I've used `<div>` as well which is straight from the Thymeleaf examples:

[image]

Many of the answers here and other sources are relying on xml configuration as well, which is of no use. Still, I've made Java-based beans based on those xml examples with no luck.

What steps are required to use spring security and thymeleaf integration in a spring boot app using only **Java based configuration** (if that)?

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

Comment: It's not clear from your question if this is only a problem in your IDE, or if it fails at runtime. If it does fail at runtime, some more details of that failure may help to figure out the problem.

Comment: Also, your first screenshot suggests that you need to configure IDEA to know about the schema and that you can do so in Settings > Project settings > Schemas and DTDs. Have you tried doing that?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson, I don't think it's the IDE although Thymeleaf integration with Intellij isn't great. It doesn't behave correctly at runtime in Eclipse STS either but doesn't show any errors. Yes, "I've tried every option available in the Intellij fix menu and can't get it." I've also followed enough tutorials and blogs to drive me crazy trying to fix it with countless configurations. The main thing is I'm using Boot and none of that is *supposed* to be required. I actually think I've found a workaround without using the namespace.

Comment: What version of Boot are you using? I can see that you're using Thymeleaf's Spring Security 4 integration. To work out of the box, that'll require Spring Boot 1.3. If you're using Boot 1.2, you should use Thymeleaf's Spring Security 3 integration.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson, using 1.2.6. The screenshot is just another failed attempt. Using 3 gives the exact same errors and results unfortunately. I got the workaround from a talk by Rob Winch which seems a little cleaner anyway and sets me up for better security practices too. I'm doing some testing later to make sure it's going to work well in other places and if so delete this post. The frustrating thing is it just works with the spring security taglib which makes moving to thymeleaf not fun.

Answer (score 8):

I have encountered the same issue and for me it helped to define schema locations like this:

```
<html lang="en"
  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
  xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
  xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.thymeleaf.org http://www.thymeleaf.org
  http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout
  http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4 http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4">
```

...

This includes also additional dialects for layout and spring security 4 which you can remove if you are not using them.